# Firebase realtime database add values to Recycler

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Long winded question. I have already this week set up a recycler view for my users in the firebase database. I want to do the same for user incidents. These are concussion tests. I basically copied my player list activities and tried to implement the same for the incidents. However they are stored differently in firebase . You can see this from the picture below.
I basically want to know is there a easy way to do this Ive tried a few things but no luck yet.
At the minute here is my code I am using. The error I get with this is "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String" although I think there is a few more errors.

**Incident Helper Class**

```
public class IncidentHelperClass {

    //Declare variables of the information to store in the database
    String playerId, Cervical_Spine_Activity, Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test, Memory_Questions, Observable_Signs_Test, Red_Flags_Test, Report;

    //Empty constructor
    public IncidentHelperClass() {

    }

    //Constructor
    public IncidentHelperClass(String redFlag, String observable, String memory, String gcs, String csa, String incidentReport) {

        this.Cervical_Spine_Activity = redFlag;
        this.Observable_Signs_Test = observable;
        this.Memory_Questions = memory;
        this.Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test = gcs;
        this.Cervical_Spine_Activity = csa;
        this.Report = incidentReport;
    }

    public String getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(String playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public String getCervical_Spine_Activity() {
        return Cervical_Spine_Activity;
    }

    public void setCervical_Spine_Activity(String cervical_Spine_Activity) {
        Cervical_Spine_Activity = cervical_Spine_Activity;
    }

    public String getGlasgow_Coma_Scale_Test() {
        return Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test;
    }

    public void setGlasgow_Coma_Scale_Test(String glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test) {
        Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test = glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test;
    }

    public String getMemory_Questions() {
        return Memory_Questions;
    }

    public void setMemory_Questions(String memory_Questions) {
        Memory_Questions = memory_Questions;
    }

    public String getObservable_Signs_Test() {
        return Observable_Signs_Test;
    }

    public void setObservable_Signs_Test(String observable_Signs_Test) {
        Observable_Signs_Test = observable_Signs_Test;
    }

    public String getRed_Flags_Test() {
        return Red_Flags_Test;
    }

    public void setRed_Flags_Test(String red_Flags_Test) {
        Red_Flags_Test = red_Flags_Test;
    }

    public String getReport() {
        return Report;
    }

    public void setReport(String report) {
        Report = report;
    }
```

}

**Incident Adapter**

```
public class IncidentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IncidentListAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    //Constants for the player name and id
    public static final String PLAYER_NAME = "playername";
    public static final String PLAYER_ID = "playerid";


    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String ID = "idKey";
    //Variables
    private Context context;
    //Declare a list using the UserHelperClass
    private List<IncidentHelperClass> incidentList;

    //Constructor
    public IncidentListAdapter(Context context, List<IncidentHelperClass> incidentsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.incidentList = incidentsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    //If viewHolder does  not exist create one by inflating the user_details_view
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.users_details_view, parent, false)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        //Retrieve the incident stored at the position
        final IncidentHelperClass incidents = incidentList.get(position);
        //Set the info from the UserHelperClass in the textViews
        holder.textViewRedFlag.setText(incidents.getRed_Flags_Test());
        holder.textViewObs.setText(incidents.getObservable_Signs_Test());
        holder.textViewMemory.setText(incidents.getMemory_Questions());
        holder.textViewGCS.setText(incidents.getGlasgow_Coma_Scale_Test());
        holder.textViewCSA.setText(incidents.getCervical_Spine_Activity());
        holder.textViewIncidentReport.setText(incidents.getReport());


        //Add an onClickListener to the parentView
        holder.parentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                IncidentHelperClass selectedIncident = incidentList.get(position);

                //The intent to launch the activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, RedFlagActivity.class);

                //Put the player id and name into the Intent from the playerList
                //  intent.putExtra(PLAYER_ID, player.getPlayerID());
                // intent.putExtra(PLAYER_NAME, player.getName());
                //Start the activity passed from the intent
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    //Return the amount of players
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.incidentList.size();
    }


    //ViewHolder wraps the view passed to it so RecyclerView can deal with it
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textViewRedFlag;
        private TextView textViewObs;
        private TextView textViewMemory;
        private TextView textViewGCS;
        private TextView textViewCSA;
        private TextView textViewIncidentReport;
        private View parentView;


        //Attach the variables to their views
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            this.parentView = view;
            this.textViewRedFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view_name);
            this.textViewObs = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view_email);
            this.textViewMemory = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view_phoneNo);
            this.textViewGCS = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view_emergencyContact);
            this.textViewCSA = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view_emergencyContactPhone);
            this.textViewGCS = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view_emergencyContactPhone2);
            this.textViewIncidentReport = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view_emergencyContactPhone3);
        }
    }
}
```

**Incident Activity**

```
public class IncidentListView extends AppCompatActivity {


//Class to update and display information in the recycler_view


    //Define the RecyclerView
    RecyclerView listViewIncidents;

    //Define a list to store the players
    ArrayList<IncidentHelperClass> incidentsList;
    //Define the reference to the database
    DatabaseReference reference;

    //Define the PlayerList Adapter
    IncidentListAdapter adapter;


    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String ID = "idKey";

    //Constants fot the player name and id
    public static final String PLAYER_NAME = "playername";
    public static final String PLAYER_ID = "playerid";

    //Tag for printing log details
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.users_list_recycler_view);

        //Assign the listView to the appropriate view
        // listViewPlayers = findViewById(R.id.users_list_recycler_view);
        //Assign the playersList
        incidentsList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Assign the recycler view to the correct view
        listViewIncidents = findViewById(R.id.recycler_list_view);
        //Set the adapter to an instance of the PlayerListAdapter
        listViewIncidents.setAdapter(new IncidentListAdapter(this, incidentsList));
        //Instruct the layout manager to set the layout to LinearLayout
        listViewIncidents.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedpreferences = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 0);
        String id = sharedpreferences.getString(ID, "UserID");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(ID, id);
        editor.commit();

        //Get a reference to the path required in the database
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Incidents");

        //AddValueEventListener will update the players list if any new players added
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot incidentSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Get the values defined in the UserHelperClass from the registered players in the database
                    IncidentHelperClass incident = incidentSnapshot.getValue(IncidentHelperClass.class);
                    //If a new player is created add them to the playersList
                    incidentsList.add(incident);
                }
                //What does this do??
                adapter = new IncidentListAdapter(IncidentListView.this, incidentsList);
                listViewIncidents.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                //Show Error toast to user
                Toast.makeText(IncidentListView.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Update**

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

```
//Retrieve the incident stored at the position
final StackIncidentHelperClass incidents = incidentList.get(position);
//Set the info from the UserHelperClass in the textViews
holder.textViewRedFlag.setText((CharSequence) incidents.getRed_Flags_Test());
holder.textViewObs.setText((CharSequence) incidents.getObservable_Signs_Test());
holder.textViewMemory.setText((CharSequence) incidents.getMemory_Questions());
holder.textViewGCS.setText((CharSequence) incidents.getGlasgow_Coma_Scale_Test());
holder.textViewCSA.setText((CharSequence) incidents.getCervical_Spine_Activity());
holder.textViewIncidentReport.setText((CharSequence) incidents.getReport());
```

Update Database
[image]

UPDATE
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You code crashes because of the type of these variables:

```
String Cervical_Spine_Activity, Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test, Memory_Questions, Observable_Signs_Test, Red_Flags_Test;
```

Their type is `java.util.HashMap<String, String>`.

And `Report` variable is of another absolutelly different type. You have to declare new class (lets call it `Report`) with the next content:

```
class Report {
    public String reportDetails;
    public String reportId;
    // add getters/setters/constructors if necessary
}
```

Having that information you can update `IncidentHelperClass` class members declaration:

```
public class IncidentHelperClass {

    //Declare variables of the information to store in the database
    String playerId;
    HashMap<String, String> Cervical_Spine_Activity, Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test, Memory_Questions, Observable_Signs_Test, Red_Flags_Test;
    @SerializedName("Report")
    Report report;

    //Empty constructor
    public IncidentHelperClass() {

    }

    //Constructor
    public IncidentHelperClass(HashMap<String, String> redFlag, 
                               HashMap<String, String> observable, 
                               HashMap<String, String> memory, 
                               HashMap<String, String> gcs, 
                               HashMap<String, String> csa, 
                               Report incidentReport) {

        this.Cervical_Spine_Activity = redFlag;
        this.Observable_Signs_Test = observable;
        this.Memory_Questions = memory;
        this.Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test = gcs;
        this.Cervical_Spine_Activity = csa;
        this.report = incidentReport;
    }

    public String getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(String playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getCervical_Spine_Activity() {
        return Cervical_Spine_Activity;
    }

    public void setCervical_Spine_Activity(HashMap<String, String> cervical_Spine_Activity) {
        Cervical_Spine_Activity = cervical_Spine_Activity;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getGlasgow_Coma_Scale_Test() {
        return Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test;
    }

    public void setGlasgow_Coma_Scale_Test(HashMap<String, String> glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test) {
        Glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test = glasgow_Coma_Scale_Test;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getMemory_Questions() {
        return Memory_Questions;
    }

    public void setMemory_Questions(HashMap<String, String> memory_Questions) {
        Memory_Questions = memory_Questions;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getObservable_Signs_Test() {
        return Observable_Signs_Test;
    }

    public void setObservable_Signs_Test(HashMap<String, String> observable_Signs_Test) {
        Observable_Signs_Test = observable_Signs_Test;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getRed_Flags_Test() {
        return Red_Flags_Test;
    }

    public void setRed_Flags_Test(HashMap<String, String> red_Flags_Test) {
        Red_Flags_Test = red_Flags_Test;
    }

    public Report getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
    }
}
```

After these changes, you'll have to update the code that uses these classes.

Comment: I did try this but I have a blank screen now so doesnt seem to be adding the data. The debug is saying that no setters are /field for any of the variables exist, but they def do! I added a pic above to what I changed in my adapter, it was giving me an error so I cast them to a char sequence dunno if thats causing the problem

Comment: I can take out the last .child, eg .child( RedFlagActivity) and get the new database tree like I added. Although not sure if this would cause issues later if multiple events. Is there an easy way to attach a date to it to search for/order bby?

Comment: You cannot cast `HashMap` to `CharSequence`. If you had at least a single item in the adapter your app would crash. The initial issue you have in the question about `DatabaseException` is solved. Now you need to figure out the rest if there are any issues.

Comment: @Chris, updated database model of an Incident does not match any model you or I have posted. You will get empty objects if any.

Comment: You can see that the results are stored at numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc. In my log it is saying there is no getter for these. Is it possible to do this to get the value of one and pass it into my list view. I tried creating a 1,2,3,4 etc variables but doesnt seem to be allowed. Have added pics

Comment: In my answer, you can see the model that will support the model from the first screenshot of Incidents presented.

Comment: You must move these values that are enumerated from 1 to 13 (instead of 13 there can be any positive number) under a separate level of the model. If you will store them on the same level as `Report` variable - you will not be able to get them out. If you store them separately in a different variable (in the Realtime Database model) then you can parse them as an array.